# How to pass props to a child component that is rendered in a v-for in VueJS

Tags: vuejs2, v-for, vue-props

I have the following Vue component

```
export default {
    components: {
      DimensionedImage
    },
    props: [
      'site'
    ]
  }
```

where `site` is an object:

```
{
  title: '',
  imageUrls: [],
  hostname: ''
}
```

The render function for that component looks like this:

```
<article>
  <header>
    <h1>{{this.site.title}}</h1>
  </header>
  <div class="images-container">
    <template v-for="imageUrl in this.site.imageUrls">
      <DimensionedImage :key="imageUrl" :url="imageUrl" :hostname="this.site.hostname"/>
    </template>
  </div>
</article>
```

As you can see, I want to pass `hostname` from the `site` prop into the `DimensionedImage` component, but Vue keeps telling me that `this` is undefined.

Can someone please tell me what is going on behind the scenes here, as to why `this` loses its context? And then how can I actually fix the code such that I can pass `hostname` from `this.site` into the child component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While rendering data variables in template you do not need to use instance of **this** while accessing a property.

```
<article>
  <header>
    <h1>{{site.title}}</h1>
  </header>
  <div class="images-container">
    <template v-for="imageUrl in site.imageUrls">
      <DimensionedImage :key="imageUrl" :url="imageUrl" :hostname="site.hostname"/>
    </template>
  </div>
</article>
```

you can go through vue rendering [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html).

Comment: ‍♂️ Thank you Riddhi. I knew it was going to be something simple